# I am looking for examples of polyandrous insects?

Tags: entomology, reproduction

This is for a homework assignment, and yet I am not able find any references that can help me find example of polyandrous insects.

Does anyone have any references or suggestions on where to look?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10973716 what about this one

Comment: The concept is sort of difficult to apply to insects, since they dont form pairs. However, females mating with multiple males is common (maybe the norm).